# Problem installing Perl module Sys::Info::Driver::Linux

Tags: drivers, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, perl

I am running Linux on Windows (Ubuntu) to install a bioinformatics software ([MEME Suite - Installation Guide](https://meme-suite.org/meme/doc/install.html?man_type=web)). Please bear in mind I do not have much experience using Linux.

I am following the instructions and I need to install some Perl modules.

I was able to install all the required ones via  `sudo cpan` except `Sys::Info`.

When I run `sudo cpan Sys::Info` this is the first error I find on the log:

> Running install for module 'Sys::Info'
> Checksum for
> /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/B/BU/BURAK/Sys-Info-0.7811.tar.gz ok
> 'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
> Configuring B/BU/BURAK/Sys-Info-0.7811.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
> Checking if your kit is complete...
> Looks good
> Warning: prerequisite Sys::Info::Driver::Linux 0.78 not found.

Then, when it tries to install `Sys::Info::Driver::Linux`, I get the following error:

> t/03-basic.t ............. UNAME: Linux DESKTOP-IO6J8UE
> 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft #1237-Microsoft Sat Sep 11 14:32:00 PST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> t/03-basic.t ............. 1/? Use of uninitialized value $name in
> string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.                                                    Use of
> uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> Use of uninitialized value $name in string eq at
> /root/.cpan/build/Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905-8/blib/lib/Sys/Info/Driver/Linux/OS.pm
> line 102.
> I can not open file /proc/swaps for reading: No such file or directory
> at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Test/Sys/Info/Driver.pm line 92.
> Looks like your test exited with 2 just after 65.

Probably it has something to do with my Linux on Windows installation, but I am completely lost. I can provide the full log if needed.

EDIT: I found the OS.pm file and the possible error:

```
# user methods
sub is_root {
    return 0 if defined &Sys::Info::EMULATE;
    my $name = login_name();
    my $id   = POSIX::geteuid();
    my $gid  = POSIX::getegid();
    return 0 if $@;
    return 0 if ! defined $id || ! defined $gid;
    return $id == 0 && $gid == 0 && $name eq 'root';
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tests are often omitted : `sudo apt install libsys-info-driver-linux-perl ` →  **universe** ....... https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/perl/ . ..... Alternatively → Sys-Info-Driver-Linux-0.7905.tar.gz → `perl Makefile.PL && make && sudo make install`

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to finally install them via `sudo apt install libsys-info-perl`     `